# Big endian and little endian in decimal

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, endianness

I need to print the value in a 32 bit register.There are various print settings possible. The program should support display as little endian or big endian and hex or decimal. I am really confused about the concept of endianness.

For example, say , if the value in register is 0x1000FFE7. If the print setting is big endian and hex, I print it as E7FF0010 and if it is little endian I print it as it is. How about the print setting being decimal?

What I am doing is convert to big endian in hex and then find the corresponding decimal and print it. Does this seem correct? Or is it like it does not matter in the case of decimal?

Comment: Registers don't have endianness (right shift is always divide by two, etc.).  It only comes into play if you store a word and then read back the individual bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal representation is also affected by endianness. The transformation you need to do is the same as for hex display (so, reorder bytes, then print as usual).

More generically the code depends on your host system. It program is only supposed to run on little endian system(s), then you are right, but generally you need to change the order, if endiannes printed is not same as endianness of system code runs on.

Answer (score 0):

Which computer language you are using?
In general, little endian stores lower bytes first as compared to higher bytes first in big endian. 
Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: That is not an issue for me. I have loaded the value in the register as little endian. I just need to print them based on the selected endianness.